# R - Remove itemsets - ECLAT Algorithm

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to analyze some associations over my products. My R code is:

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(igraph)
library(iplots)

data <- read.transactions('file', sep=',')
itemsets <- eclat(data, parameter = list(supp = 0.1, maxlen = 15))
plot(itemsets, method="graph", control=list(type="items"))
```

This code is executing very well but I'm getting some products that haven't any associations as shown is image below:

[image]

There exists any way to remove this IDs from the map?

Answer (score 0):

These are itemsets with only a single item. You can call eclat with `parameters = list(minlen = 2)`. See `? eclat` for more details.